Insulate cinder block wall
The exterior walls of the first floor of our house are cinder block with brick on the outside.  The inside of the wall was painted black (not sure what that is) with furling strips then sheet rock.  In short, there is no insulation to keep the heat out (we live in Virginia).
Our plan is to install 3/4" rigid foam insulation between the furling strips and put up new sheet rock. It does not provide great insulation (R of about 3) but it is better than nothing.
What I don't know is whether we need vapor barrier, adhesive to stick the foam to the wall, or if there is a compelling reason to just leave it alone.  Also trying to head off the unknown unknowns so any advice is appreciated.


Are the rooms big enough that you can stand to lose a few inches from the outside walls?   3.5 inches(a 2x4) from the blocks, will give R-15(or more depending on insulation type).

@crip659 I'm really tempted to do so, but the rooms are not terribly large and that would require reframing the windows.  That said, I'd be interested to know if that changes the vapor barrier question (I understand I'll have to frame the wall, but other than that does that make the job easier/harder)?

Vapour barrier is about the same with thin or thicker walls.  Foam insulation can be its own vapour barrier sometimes.  Not sure about block type walls above the ground if they need the barrier against them instead of the more common of having just behind the drywall.

Black is often the color of the vapor barrier when painted on the cinder block.  Ideally this would have been done on the exterior before the foundation was buried.  But if not, it might have been done on the interior of the walls.  If you can take pictures of that, it might help people better describe what you currently have.

Consider covering the wall with an additional layer of rigid foam over the firring strips after you fill those in, using longer screws to hold the sheetrock. You will need extension ring s and longer screws for the outlets, but they are available. You will only need to tack the extra layer here and there to hold it in place, until the sheetrock goes up.

@mdfst13 Picture added.  All of these walls are above grade and this paint is on all walls (even interior walls).

If you install a vapor barrier use Tyvek or an equivalent that allows water vapor but not water to pass through. NEVER use plastic as it will trap moisture in your walls and promote mold.

The bottom plate looks like a 2x3, so maybe use that width.  Drywall can go on top to make extra room space or in front of it for extra insulation.
